# How do you filter SQL error logs to display specific error messages?

Tags: sql-server, error-log

I find it hard to believe that there aren't better native tools to filter SQL Server Error Logs.  Even Windows Logs have better filtering capabilities.  I'd like the ability to remove certain events from the results or a list of events from the results or to be able to search for a very specific error/event.

Comment: How about Exec sp_readerrorlog 0,1,'text' where text is the text you want to see in SQL server errorlog. It requires little experience to see errorlog I never needed tool to find out what I required. Once you start reading it you will automatically filter out what is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one I wrote myself years ago.  This is a section of a larger stored procedure, but it works fine on its own.  You can modify the filters to remove unwanted entires as well as highlight others.

```
print ' '
print ' '
print '==================='
print '== SQL Errorlogs =='
print '==================='
print ' '


declare
  @FirstLog      smallint, 
  @LastLog       smallint,
  @BufferRecords smallint,
  @SQL           varchar(2000),
  @Output        varchar(2000)

select
  @FirstLog      = 0, --> Defaults to current logfile
  @LastLog       = 1, --> Defaults to logfile immediately preceding current
  @BufferRecords = 4  --> Used to give a frame of reference to the error message

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Date Created: July 11, 2005
-- Author:       Bill McEvoy
-- Description:  This procedure combines and parses the SQL Error Logs.  Entries of special 
--               interest are marked which allows the operator to quickly scan the output for
--               errors.  Entries of interest are removed from the output.  Entries before and
--               after the errors are included to give a frame of reference.
--               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Date Revised: December 7, 2006
-- Author:       Bill McEvoy
-- Reason:       I converted this procedure to support SQL Server 2005
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set nocount on
declare @count  smallint,
        @alert  char(5)

select  @count  = 0,
        @SQL    = '',
        @output = '',
        @alert  = '---->'

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Validate input parameters                                       --
---------------------------------------------------------------------

IF (@FirstLog > @LastLog)
BEGIN
  select @lastLog = @FirstLog + 1
END


---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- M A I N   P R O C E S S I N G                                   --
---------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                                 --
-- Create work tables                                              --
--                                                                 --
-- Import SQL Error Logs                                           --
--                                                                 --
-- Remove unwanted entries                                         --
--                                                                 --
-- Mark items of interest                                          --
--                                                                 --
-- Generate report                                                 --
--                                                                 --
---------------------------------------------------------------------


---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Create work tables                                              --
---------------------------------------------------------------------

IF (object_id('tempdb..#ERRORLOG') IS NOT NULL)
  drop table #ERRORLOG

CREATE TABLE #ERRORLOG
(
  LogID       int identity primary key clustered,
  LogDate     datetime NULL,
  ProcessInfo varchar(12) NULL, 
  Alert       char(5) default ' ',
  LogEntry    varchar(900) NULL,
  Row         smallint NULL

)

-- Add indexes
create index [IX_ERRORLOG_Alert]    on dbo.[#ERRORLOG](Alert)    with fillfactor = 98 on [PRIMARY]
create index [IX_ERRORLOG_LogEntry] on dbo.[#ERRORLOG](LogEntry) with fillfactor = 98 on [PRIMARY]


---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Import SQL Error Logs                                           --
---------------------------------------------------------------------

select @count = @FirstLog



  WHILE (@Count <= @LastLog) 
  BEGIN
    insert into #ERRORLOG (ProcessInfo, Alert, LogEntry) values (' ','',' ')
    insert into #ERRORLOG (ProcessInfo, Alert, LogEntry) values (' ','',' ')
    insert into #ERRORLOG (ProcessInfo, Alert, LogEntry) values (' ','',' ')
    insert into #ERRORLOG (ProcessInfo, Alert, LogEntry) values (' ','','------------------------------')
    select @output = '-- Processing: ERRORLOG' + case(@count) when 0 then '    ' else '.' + convert(char(3), @count) end + ' --'
    insert into #ERRORLOG (ProcessInfo, Alert, LogEntry) values (' ','',@output)
    insert into #ERRORLOG (ProcessInfo, Alert, LogEntry) values (' ','','------------------------------')
    insert into #ERRORLOG (ProcessInfo, Alert, LogEntry) values (' ','',' ')
    select @SQL = 'exec master..sp_readerrorlog ' + convert(varchar(3), @count)
    insert into #errorlog (LogDate, ProcessInfo, LogEntry)
    execute (@SQL)
    select @count = @count + 1
  END

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Remove unwanted entries                                         --
---------------------------------------------------------------------


delete 
  from #ERRORLOG 
 where LogEntry like '%Bypassing recovery for database%'
    or LogEntry like '%Setting database option ANSI_WARNINGS%'
    or LogEntry like '%Log backed up with following information:%'
    or LogEntry like '%Login succeeded for user%'
    or LogEntry like '%found 0 errors and repaired 0 errors%'
    or LogEntry like '%Database differential changes%'
    or LogEntry like '%The certificate was successfully loaded%'
    or LogEntry like '%this is an informational message only%'
    or LogEntry like '%logging sql server messages in file%'
    or LogEntry like '%Recovery complete.%'
    or LogEntry like '%Starting up database ''ERROR_LOGGING''%'
    or LogEntry like '%Database backed up: Database: %'
    or LogEntry like '%Log backed up: Database: %'
    or LogEntry like '%allocate%'




---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Mark items of interest                                          --
---------------------------------------------------------------------

update #ERRORLOG
   set Alert = @alert
 where (LogEntry like '%err%'
    or  LogEntry like '%exception%'
    or  LogEntry like '%violation%'
    or  LogEntry like '%warn%'
    or  LogEntry like '%kill%'
    or  LogEntry like '%dead%'
    or  LogEntry like '%encounter%'
    or  LogEntry like '%cannot%'
    or  LogEntry like '%could%'
    or  LogEntry like '%fail%'
    or  LogEntry like '%full%'
    or  LogEntry like '%not%'
    or  LogEntry like '%terminate%'
    or  LogEntry like '%bypass%'
    or  LogEntry like '%recover%'
    or  LogEntry like '%roll%'
    or  LogEntry like '%upgrade%'
    or  LogEntry like '%victim%'
    or  LogEntry like '%stop%'
    or  LogEntry like '%shut%'
    or  LogEntry like '%timed out%'
    or  LogEntry like '%truncate%'
    or  LogEntry like '%terminat%')
   and  (ProcessInfo <> ' ' or  ProcessInfo IS NULL)



---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Generate report                                                 --
---------------------------------------------------------------------


BEGIN

  -- Show entries of interest + buffer records
  select A.LogID,
         'Date'       = isnull(convert(varchar(19), A.LogDate, 120), ''),
         A.ProcessInfo,
         A.Alert,
         'Descripton' = left(A.logEntry, 250)
    from #ERRORLOG A
   join (select LogID from #ERRORLOG where Alert = @alert) B  on (A.LogID >= (B.LogID - @BufferRecords))
                                                           and (A.LogID <= (B.LogID + @BufferRecords))

  -- Show informational records
  union
  select A.LogID,
         'Date'       = isnull(convert(varchar(19), A.LogDate, 120), ''),
         A.ProcessInfo,
         A.Alert,
         'Descripton' = left(A.logEntry, 250)
    from #ERRORLOG A
   where ProcessInfo = ''
   order by A.LogID
END
```

Comment: It should be noted that if you have not cycled your errorlogs lately, this script will take a while before it finished chugging through it all